# python,django, solr, haystack: django templates context error when editing solr_build_schema BaseCommand.add_argument()

Tags: python, django, solr, django-haystack

Please help....i am trying use solr, pysolr and haystack on my django site search. I have edited the haystack build_solr_schema script to use BaseCommand.add_argument(), removing the default options_list. Below are my versions used;
Python 3.5.2
Django 1.11.11
solr-7.3.0
django-haystack 2.4.0
pysolr 3.7.0

```
# encoding: utf-8

from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals

import sys
from optparse import make_option
from django.core.exceptions import ImproperlyConfigured
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from django.template import Context, loader
from haystack import constants
from haystack.backends.solr_backend import SolrSearchBackend

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = "Generates a Solr schema that reflects the indexes."

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        # positional arguments
        parser.add_argument("-f", "--filename", action="store", type="string", dest="filename",
                help='If provided, directs output to a file instead of stdout.',),
       # optional positional arguments
       parser.add_argument("-u", "--using", action="store", type="string", dest="using", default=constants.DEFAULT_ALIAS,
                help='If provided, chooses a connection to work with.')

      """
       base_options = (
       make_option("-f", "--filename", action="store", type=str, dest="filename",
                help='If provided, directs output to a file instead of stdout.'),
       make_option("-u", "--using", action="store", type=str, dest="using", default=constants.DEFAULT_ALIAS,
                help='If provided, chooses a connection to work with.'),
       )
      option_list = BaseCommand.option_list + base_options
      """
     def  handle(self, **options):
         """Generates a Solr schema that reflects the indexes."""
         using = options.get('using')
         schema_xml = self.build_template(using=using)

         if options.get('filename'):
            self.write_file(options.get('filename'), schema_xml)
         else:
             self.print_stdout(schema_xml)

    def build_context(self, using):
        from haystack import connections, connection_router
        backend = connections[using].get_backend()

        if not isinstance(backend, SolrSearchBackend):
            raise ImproperlyConfigured("'%s' isn't configured as a SolrEngine)." % backend.connection_alias)

        content_field_name, fields = backend.build_schema(connections[using].get_unified_index().all_searchfields())
        return Context({
            'content_field_name': content_field_name,
            'fields': fields,
            'default_operator': constants.DEFAULT_OPERATOR,
            'ID': constants.ID,
            'DJANGO_CT': constants.DJANGO_CT,
            'DJANGO_ID': constants.DJANGO_ID,
        })

    def build_template(self, using):
        t = loader.get_template('search_configuration/solr.xml')
        c = self.build_context(using=using)
        return t.render(c)

    def print_stdout(self, schema_xml):
        sys.stderr.write("\n")
        sys.stderr.write("\n")
        sys.stderr.write("\n")
        sys.stderr.write("Save the following output to 'schema.xml' and place it in your Solr configuration directory.\n")
        sys.stderr.write("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n")
        sys.stderr.write("\n")
        print(schema_xml)

    def write_file(self, filename, schema_xml):
        schema_file = open(filename, 'w')
        schema_file.write(schema_xml)
        schema_file.close()
```

The error is gives is given below as

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 356, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
    File "/home/tochie/virtual_django/myblog_env/mysite/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/haystack/management/commands/build_solr_schema.py", line 39, in handle
schema_xml = self.build_template(using=using)
    File "/home/tochie/virtual_django/myblog_env/mysite/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/haystack/management/commands/build_solr_schema.py", line 66, in build_template
    return t.render(c)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 64, in render
    context = make_context(context, request, autoescape=self.backend.engine.autoescape)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/template/context.py", line 287, in make_context
   raise TypeError('context must be a dict rather than %s.' % context.__class__.__name__)
   TypeError: context must be a dict rather than Context.
```

Please help if there is any other way of solving this issue,without having to edit haystack's build_solr_schema or any other solution to this problem..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error is coming from Haystack, so it looks as if your version of Haystack does not support Django 1.11.

Try upgrading Haystack. Version 2.8.1, the latest release at the time of writing, supports Django 1.11.

I can't find anything explicit in the docs, but [this commit](https://github.com/django-haystack/django-haystack/commit/1dc51ad8c8583eb17cdaaf8f4c191a7ecaf218e3) suggests that support for Django 1.11 was added in version 2.7.